# Objective C - Draw multiple arc within circle

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics

I am trying to draw arc within a circle and fill the arc's. Here is the code i am using:

```
CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        CGContextAddEllipseInRect(ctx, rect);
        CGContextSetFillColor(ctx, CGColorGetComponents([[clrArray objectAtIndex:0] CGColor]));
        CGContextFillPath(ctx);

        CGFloat radius = 12.5;

        CGFloat startAngle1 = DegreesToRadians(0);
        CGFloat endAngle1 = DegreesToRadians(135);

        CGFloat startAngle2 = DegreesToRadians(135);
        CGFloat endAngle2 = DegreesToRadians(270);

        //draw arc
        CGPoint center = CGPointMake(radius,radius);

        //Arc 1
        CGContextAddArc(ctx,
                        center.x,
                        center.y,
                        radius,
                        startAngle1,
                        endAngle1,
                        YES);
        [(UIColor*)[clrArray objectAtIndex:1] set];
        CGContextFillPath(ctx);

        //Arc 2
        CGContextAddArc(ctx,
                        center.x,
                        center.y,
                        radius,
                        startAngle2,
                        endAngle2,
                        YES);
        [(UIColor*)[clrArray objectAtIndex:2] set];
        CGContextFillPath(ctx);
```

It is not drawing right. If i only provide one arc then if its angle is less than 180 then it is also not daring right. What i am doing wrong?

**Edit:** Here is the image of what is happening
[image]

I used start angle 0 and end angle 45 in this image

Comment: it is "not drawing right" in **what sense?**

Comment: It is drawing but drawing it wrong. like i gave the angel 0 that will be the x=0 y=center.y and 135 will be the angle on the circle. But instead it is drawing it in the bottom right corner.

Comment: And if i give end angle it is drawing accurately on half of the circle end and start point will be the same as i mentioned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got another solution using bezier Path

```
CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

        CGFloat radius = 50.0/2.0;
        CGPoint center = CGPointMake(radius,radius);

        CGFloat startAngle1 = DegreesToRadians(0);
        CGFloat endAngle1 = DegreesToRadians(120);

        CGFloat startAngle2 = DegreesToRadians(120);
        CGFloat endAngle2 = DegreesToRadians(240);

        CGContextSaveGState(ctx);

        UIBezierPath* clip1 = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:center
                                                            radius:radius
                                                        startAngle:startAngle1
                                                          endAngle:endAngle1
                                                         clockwise:YES];
        [clip1 addLineToPoint:center];
        [clip1 closePath];
        [clip1 addClip];

        UIBezierPath *arc1 = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50)];
        [[UIColor blackColor] set];
        [arc1 fill];

        CGContextRestoreGState(ctx);

        CGContextSaveGState(ctx);

        UIBezierPath* clip2 = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:center
                                                             radius:radius
                                                         startAngle:startAngle2
                                                           endAngle:endAngle2
                                                          clockwise:YES];
        [clip2 addLineToPoint:center];
        [clip2 closePath];
        [clip2 addClip];

        UIBezierPath *arc2 = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50)];
        [[UIColor orangeColor] set];
        [arc2 fill];

        CGContextRestoreGState(ctx);
```